# Expanding size of a list

Tags: c++

I am writing a class that holds strings. It is basically a container that will hold strings. I am wondering how to expand the size of the container as the container grows larger.

Right now I have an array holding the strings and the size of the array is set at 10. I've thought about creating a two dimensional array but since the size would be arbitrarily assigned anyway, do not think that would make any difference.

```
class stringlist {
public:
    typedef std::string str;
    void push(str);
    void pop();
    void print();
private:
    str container[10];
};
void stringlist::push(str s)
{
    size_t sz = sizeof(container) / sizeof(*container);
    str* ptr = container;
    while(ptr[sz] != "" && *ptr != "")
        ++ptr;
    *ptr = s;
}
void stringlist::pop()
{
    size_t sz = sizeof(container) / sizeof(*container);
    str* ptr = container;
    while(ptr != ptr + sz)
        ++ptr;
    *ptr = "";
}
void stringlist::print()
{
    size_t sz = sizeof(container) / sizeof(*container);
    str* ptr = container;
    while(ptr[sz] != "" && *ptr != "")
        std::cout << *ptr++ << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

`EDIT`

Basically I am looking for some kind of dynamic memory allocation. `str* container = new str[N]` where `N` can be specified. But I am not sure how to implement without knowing N beforehand.

If I use constructors I get an error:

```
public:
    stringlist() : N(15) {}
    stringlist(size_t sz) : N(sz) {}
private:
    str* container = new str[N];
    size_t N;
```

`ERROR`

```
a.out(29866,0x7fff76388310) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=3377629375143936) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc
```

`EDIT`

I actually got it to work with the constructor method. I had the value of `N` begin set after allocating the container which gave me the error. I switched the order and works.

`NOTE:` This does not yet solve the problem of growing the list as I add elements.

`_____________________________________________________________________________________`

`REFLECTION`

It seems that if I change the value of the data member `N`, the size of the array reallocates to that size. I thought that since the array was created when the object was created the array won't change sizes but after writing and running some functions it is doing exactly that.

Comment: `typedef std::list<std::string> StringList`?

Comment: You could read in 1 string at a time and increment the count. Then after you have the count, allocate a string array with memory, but really std::list if the way to go

Comment: what is str*? Is it meant to be a char or a string?

Comment: `str` is `std::string`.

Comment: do you have to use dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: @MatthewPigram. With this method I would require a temporary container?

Comment: just a single string that you reassign each time, not the most elegant solution by any means but it will work, also it means reading through the strings twice, once to get the count, and again after memory has been allocated to load in the strings

Comment: @MatthewPigram. I don't see how it is possible to change the size of a container once it is set whether it is dynamically allocated or not. I can't seem to create a temp container either because I will not be able to delete the originally allocated memory and create it with the new size within the class.

Answer (score 1):

`str container[10];` is a fixed size array of ten strings. This means your class will have 10 strings in it even if you haven't added any yet.

You might want consider using a `std::vector` to store your strings in, inside your class. This will allow you to grow and shrink the container as you see fit.

However if you're going to use a stl container inside your class, I don't see why you wouldn't just using a `std::list` to start with.

Comment: alternatively he could use dynamic memory, but its a fair bit more finicky when std::list exists

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a stack-like container (where the only useful operations are pushing, poping and possibly iterating) you might want to use a linked list instead of an indexed one.

More on linked lists [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/Lw6AC542)

Otherwise you'll have to expand the list and copy all objects from the old list to the new one whenever you "grow out" of the current list.

Comment: Dochevsky this is what my solution will involve, if you must do this manually (i.e. not allowed to use stl classes) it would be far better to create your own linked list implementation using pointers, which is pretty easy to do and can expand almost indefinitely-ish

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are static data structures, meaning they have fixed data size. You can either allocate dynamically memory by creating & using the appropriate data structure for your cause, OR (recommended) you can use STL's Generic classes, such as *vector, list, map*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that if I change the value of the data member N, the size of the array reallocates to that size. I thought that since the array was created when the object was created the array won't change sizes but after writing and running some functions it is doing exactly that.

Unless I'm misunderstanding you, it sounds like you mean that you get the desired behavior simply by increasing N.

If you don't reallocate the array to the new size you'll end up with undefined behavior, sometimes working and sometimes crashing. Should another object be assigned the space right behind your array it'll be overwritten if you keep adding elements to your list.

Comment: Yes. I updated my `push` function to increase `N` by 1 if the list is already full and also a resize function to give `N` a new value. Actually I can't check it when `N` is larger than the number of elements but it seems to be the case when `N` needs to be increased to accommodate new elements.

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet similar to above like what JBarberU said is a linked list. However if you would like it to be indexed you could create a dynamic array class that has a size and a capacity, every time you add a string to the array increment the size and if you are going to add to the array and it would exceed the size then create a new array, twice as large and copy all of the values over.

Comment: Remember that SO is not a threaded forum. You better provide an answer that can stand on its own.